# Notepad++: Finding a particular Text and replacing in Parent line

Tags: notepad++

I want to replace enabled="true" to enabled="false" in below lines of my file in notepad++. My file has large number of such lines which needs to be replaced. Pl. help me on same. (with reg exp of notepad++)

```
<Action sortkey="002" enabled="true" desc="Macro_APP_Open" profile="Safety_Type_1_MacroAPPOpen">
<Action sortkey="003" enabled="true" desc="Change_From_Portal_To_Project_View" profile="Change_From_Portal_To_Project_View">
<Action sortkey="04" enabled="true" desc="Project_Open_from_OpenPath_SafetyCert_ProjectView" profile="Click_FirstSteps_PortalView">
<Action sortkey="005" enabled="true" desc="Project_SaveAs" profile="EnterProjectDetails_ToSave">
```

Comment: <Action sortkey="04" enabled="true" desc="Project_Open_from_OpenPath_SafetyCert_ProjectView" profile="Click_FirstSteps_PortalView">
<Action sortkey="005" enabled="true" desc="Project_SaveAs" profile="EnterProjectDetails_ToSave">
<Action sortkey="002" enabled="true" desc="Macro_APP_Open" profile="Safety_Type_1_MacroAPPOpen">
 <Action sortkey="003" enabled="true" desc="Change_From_Portal_To_Project_View" profile="Change_From_Portal_To_Project_View">

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<Action sortkey="\d+".+?enabled="\Ktrue`
- Replace with: `false`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<Action sortkey="   : literally
\d+                 : 1 or more digits
"                   : double quote
.+?                 : 1 or more any character, not greedy
enabled="           : literally
\K                  : forget all we have seen until this position
true                : literally
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<Action sortkey="002" enabled="false" desc="Macro_APP_Open" profile="Safety_Type_1_MacroAPPOpen">
<Action sortkey="003" enabled="false" desc="Change_From_Portal_To_Project_View" profile="Change_From_Portal_To_Project_View">
<Action sortkey="04" enabled="false" desc="Project_Open_from_OpenPath_SafetyCert_ProjectView" profile="Click_FirstSteps_PortalView">
<Action sortkey="005" enabled="false" desc="Project_SaveAs" profile="EnterProjectDetails_ToSave">
```

Comment: I used above Reg Exp, only text is getting highlighted, it is not replaced. Can you pl. let me know what is wrong ? will notepad++ version matters. iam using v6.9.2

Comment: i tried to put my CTRL H window with reg exp. But i can't place it here.

Comment: DO i need to press replace all button or can i click replace button

Comment: @VinodHejib: 1) version 6.9.2 is OK. 2) Ctrl + H is used to open the replacement window within Notepad++ 3) "Replace all" will replace all occurrences and "Replace" will replace only one instance.